# Removing white spaces and punctuation from list

Tags: python, list

```
def wordlist (l: list) -> list:
    '''Returns a wordlist without white spaces and punctuation'''
    result = []
    table = str.maketrans('!()-[]:;"?.,', '            ')
    for x in l:
        n = x.translate(table)
        n = x.strip()
        n = x.split()
        if n != []:
            result.extend(n)
    return result
```

The function is supposed to work like this:

```
print(wordlist(['  Testing', '????', 'function!!']))
```

should yield:

```
['Testing', 'function']
```

but the code I have above yields:

```
['Testing', '??', 'function!!']
```

So I assume I'm doing something incorrectly with the code in regards to removing punctuation--where should I fix it? Any other suggestions to simplify the code would also be appreciated (since I figured it's a bit long-winded).

Comment: Are you sure you want to test ` n != []` rather than `n != ""`

Comment: I took out in the end since it didn't have any significance to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to chain `translate(table)`, `strip()` and `split()` calls?

Then

```
n = x.translate(table)
n = x.strip()
n = x.split()
```

should be

```
n = x.translate(table)
n = n.strip() # change x to n
n = n.split() # same here
```

or

```
n = x.translate(table).split()
```

No need for intermediate `strip()`.

As for further simplification, you don't have to check the emptiness of `n`, it looks like a premature optimization to me:

```
if n != []: # you can remove this line
    result.extend(n)
```

The result:

```
def wordlist (l: list) -> list:
    '''Returns a wordlist without white spaces and punctuation'''
    result = []
    table = str.maketrans('!()-[]:;"?.,', '            ')
    for x in l:
        result.extend(x.translate(table).split())
    return result
```

You can even replace that loop with a list comprehension.

Comment: Is there a way to remove ALL punctuation? I'm not sure what constitutes as punctuation, so all the ones I thought of are there, but does Python have a built-in punctuation list that I can use for the translation?

Comment: @RamonHallan yes, it does, `import string` and use `str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lot cleaner to just use `re.sub` here:

```
import re
clean = re.compile(r'[!()\-\[\]:;"?.,\s]')

words = ['  Testing', '????', 'function!!']
result = list(filter(bool, (clean.sub('', w) for w in words)))
print result
# ['Testing', 'function']
```